# What does the phrase "peer down" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "peer down" in the following sentence:

[You peer down on a grassy field of play, and drag three of the same thing closer together.](https://apps.apple.com/gb/story/mighty-moreish-merging/id1491784507)

For more context, it's about a game app. Here is another excerpt from the same source:

[Then pop! They merge into one, more valuable, item. And the more you smoosh things together, the bigger and grander the items get....So after starting out with little weeds and shrubs, you’ll merge your way up to flowers that yield yellow hearts (which can also be merged to ‘heal’ greyed out areas you can’t merge in).](https://apps.apple.com/gb/story/mighty-moreish-merging/id1491784507)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the word 'peer' with 'look'

"Look down"

From the Cambridge dictionary -

Peer - "to look carefully or with difficulty"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peer